# BeautifulSoup4 how to check if a tag has a specific child tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
b = soup.find('body')

for t in b.find_all(recursive=False):
    if not t.find(['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']):
        print(t.get_text())
```

which is supposed to print all the child tags of `t` that aren't `'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'` (i.e. headings).

Instead, it prints nothing. How do I fix this if statement so that the code prints only when the main tag doesn't have the specified child tags?

Comment: `b.find_all(recursive=False)` defines a tag that you want to find.                                 
reference: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument

Comment: Are you sure your `body` has any tags which don't have a header child? Because your code should work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Python 3.8.1)

Agree with @Manali. Add a tag you want to search-for, just like you did in **soup.find('body')**.

```
soup.html.find_all("<tag name>", recursive=False)
```

(Edit):
Cannot use TAG directly, use TAG.NAME instead.
Use:      `if t.name not in ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']`

instead of:     `if not t.find(['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']):`

Otherwise try the following snippet:

```
b = soup.find('body')
children = b.findChildren(recursive=False)
for child in children:
    if child.name not in ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']:
        print(child.name)
```

This should give you the desired results.

Comment: But I'm trying to print out all tags except for headings tags. How exactly could I do that?

Comment: Calling _findChildren(recursive=False)_ should return the _first child only_. I have updated the code snippet.